# Pass a POJO to Subreport in Jasper Reports

Tags: hibernate, jasper-reports, subreport

I have a Hibernate POJO with 
 1.an one-to-one association  to another object
 2.one-to-many association(collection) with another object

I am trying to create a Jasper report with these associations going to subreports.
For many-to-one association I am passing the datasource as follows:

```
<subreport>
 <reportElement x="40" y="16" width="100" height="30"/>
 <dataSourceExpression>
   <![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{phones})]]>
 </dataSourceExpression>
 <subreportExpression>
    <![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport1.jasper"]]>
 </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

This works fine. And here is the way I defined it for one-to-one association

```
<subreport>
 <reportElement x="25" y="91" width="200" height="59"/>
 <dataSourceExpression>
   <![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource([$F{batchHeaderRecord}] as java.lang.Object[])]]>
 </dataSourceExpression>
 <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "batchHeaderReport.jasper"]]>
 </subreportExpression>
</subreport>
```

But this one is not working. Can some one please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: What is a type of `$F{batchHeaderRecord}` field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource([$F{batchHeaderRecord}] as java.lang.Object[])
```

is not valid Java code. Just use

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Collections.singleton($F{batchHeaderRecord}))
```

or

```
new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanArrayDataSource(new Object[] {$F{batchHeaderRecord}})
```

Comment: Thanks..Tried them out. JRBeanCollectionDataSource is working fine. But using JRBeanArrayDataSource is giving me the following error:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: calculator_tdsSample_1325043312140_397478: 187: No expression for the array constructor call at line: 187 column: 91. File: calculator_tdsSample_1325043312140_397478 @ line 187, column 91

Comment: Hi,
I'm facing same issue. but with different scenario. I'm trying to display list in table but my list have one to one relation with another entity like MemberList have one to one relation with Employee
I want to display Member_ID | Employee.FullName | in same table.
Please help

Answer (score 1):

Set `language` to **Java** for the report to fix the groovy error.